# REGEXP_REPLACE returns Invalid Number Error when used multi-line

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         TRIM(NVL(COL_A,''))||', '||TRIM(NVL(COL_B,''))||', '||TRIM(NVL(COL_C,'')),
         '\s{2,}|\t{1,}',
         ' ',
         'm'
       )
FROM   <table_name>
```

This returns invalid number `ora-01722` if I use multi-line option ('m').
The query works correctly if I remove 'm'.

Any opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax for `REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) is:

> [image: REGEXP_REPLACE syntax diagram]

You want `'m'` as the 6th parameter and not the 4th (which is the `position` to start matching from and expects a `NUMBER` value):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         TRIM(COL_A)||', '||TRIM(COL_B)||', '||TRIM(COL_C),
         '\s{2,}|\t{1,}',
         ' ',
         1,
         0,
         'm'
       )
FROM   <table_name>
```

*Note: In Oracle `''` is the same as `NULL` so `NVL(value,'')` is the same as `NVL(value, NULL)` which is the same as just `value`. so you can remove all the `NVL` function calls.*